# While Loop complication in guess the number game

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

So I am making a guess the number game in Python 3

After the whole process, I want my while loop to generate another number so that I can start the game again without running the program again.
Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, and if you could provide me with some insight on how to use the while loop, it'll be much appreciated.

Here's the code :

```
import random

while True:

    number = random.randint(1, 1000)

    count = 0

    guessed = input("Enter the number you guessed: ")
    count += 1

    if int(guessed) < number:
        print("You guessed too low")
    elif int(guessed) > number:
        print("You guessed too high")
    elif int(guessed) == number:
        print(f'You guessed right and it took you {count} guesses to the right number which is {number}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the code you pasted was a typo (on indentation), but I may have accidentally changed your implementation.

Regardless, you should just add another `while` loop, and a break condition when the user gets it right.

```
import random
while True:
    number = random.randint(1, 1000)
    count = 0
    while True:                                   # Added, and added another layer of indentation
        guessed = input("Enter the number you guessed: ")
        count += 1

        if int(guessed) < number:
            print("You guessed too low")
        elif int(guessed) > number:
            print("You guessed too high")
        elif int(guessed) == number:
            print(f'You guessed right and it took you {count} guesses to the right number which is {number}')
            break                                 # Added
```

In doing so, the code will keep looping to guess the correct number until they are correct. And then generate a new number to guess. However this code will never end unless you add another breaking condition (such as setting a flag the `while` loop will check to break out of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some quick code that prompts the user if they want to continue playing or not and then loops through and continues the game with a new number if they want to. I also fixed some minor bugs. Your count kept getting reset in the loop so it would always say you found it in 1 try.

```
import random

def promptUser():
  user_continue = input("Do you want to continue playing? y/n")
  if (user_continue == 'y'):
    number = random.randint(1, 10)
    game(0, number)

def game(count, number):
  while True:
    guessed = input("Enter the number you guessed: ")
    count += 1

    if int(guessed) < number:
      print("You guessed too low")
    elif int(guessed) > number:
      print("You guessed too high")
    elif int(guessed) == number:
      print(f'You guessed right and it took you {count} guesses to the right number which is {number}')
      promptUser()
      break

promptUser()
```

Comment: Thankyou understood quite a lot from this!!

Comment: @AmanVinayak Glad to help! Be sure to accept answer if it fixed your issue :)